# jQuery.contains() returns wrong ouput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to use jQuery.contains(parent,child) to check if an element is a child of another the evaluation of the function returns true, eventhough the 2 elements are not subsequent, please find it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1xcs8gw/2/)

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="clickme()">Click me</button>
```

**JS**

```
function clickme() {
  parent = $("#parent")
  child = $("#child")
  alert(jQuery.contains(parent,child))
}
```

**the parent element has the following attributes**

```
<li id="parent"><a class="dropmenu" selectdropvalue="8" geolocation="IN" href="javascript:void(0);" redirect="https://www.rohm.co.kr/">한국 - 한국어</a></li>
```

**the child element am checking has the below**

```
<span>
  <a style="width: 156px; display: block;" href="javascript:void(0);" id="portals-button" class="ui-selectmenu headlang">
  <span class="ui-selectmenu-status" id="child">Europe - English</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon"></span>
</a>
</span>
```

is that the correct way to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/ :

> The `$.contains()` method returns `true` if the DOM element provided by the second argument is a descendant of the DOM element provided by the first argument, **whether it is a direct child or nested more deeply**.

So it will still return `true` if I'm interpreting your screenshots (avoid that btw!) correctly: `<span>` is child element of `<a>`, which is child element of `<li>`, and you are using `contains(element li, element span)`.

**Edit considering your latest edit and jsfiddle:**

From https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/ :

> Note: The first argument **must be a DOM element**, not a jQuery object or plain JavaScript object.

Comment: I want to check if the parent element **has** the child element in his child nodes, not based on the **types** of elements

Comment: That's totally clear because that is what `contains()` does. But if you don't provide the parent element as a DOM element as requested by jQuery documentation, it's unlikely to show the expected results.

Comment: thanks alot, when I used **document.getElementById** the result returned false as expected

Comment: You're welcome. Though you could have had that answer immediately by providing some code instead of screenshots... ;)